How can you ensure that you can only enter numbers, and optionally decimals?
I have an Input-component in Blazor. I only want to input digits and optional decimals.
And I get an error: "Unhandled exception rendering component: event.preventDefault is not a function"

The component must show numbers with dots in the thousands.

And commas with decimals.

And a decimal number must be stored.
@inherits InputNumber<decimal?>
 @using System.Globalization
 @using System.Text.RegularExpressions

 <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
        id="@_id"
        class="@CssClass"
        value="@_stringValue"
        @onkeydown="OnKeyDown"
        @oninput="OnInput"
        @onchange="OnValueChanged" />

 <script>
     window.validateInput = function (inputId, allowDecimals, event) {
         const key = event.key;

         if (
             (key >= '0' && key <= '9') ||
             key === 'Backspace' ||
             key === 'Tab' ||
             key === 'Enter' ||
             key === 'ArrowLeft' ||
             key === 'ArrowRight' ||
             (allowDecimals && (key === ',' || key === '.'))
         ) {
             return true;  
         }

         event.preventDefault();

         return false;
     }

     window.formatNumberInput = function (value, allowDecimals) {
         let cleanedValue = value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '');
         let parts = cleanedValue.split(',');
         let integerPart = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
         let formattedValue = integerPart;

         if (allowDecimals && parts.length > 1) {
             formattedValue += ',' + parts[1].substring(0, 2);  
         }

         return formattedValue;
     }
 </script>

 @code {
     private string _id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     private string? _stringValue;
     private string? _currentValue;

     [Inject] IJSRuntime _jsRuntime { get; set; }

     [Parameter] public string FormatString { get; set; } = "#,##0.00";
     [Parameter] public bool AllowDecimals { get; set; } = true;

     protected override void OnParametersSet()
     {
         if (Value.HasValue)
         {
             _stringValue = Value.Value.ToString(FormatString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
         }
         else
         {
             _stringValue = null;
         }
     }

     private async Task OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
     {
         await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("validateInput", _id, AllowDecimals, e);
     }

     private async Task OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
     {
         _currentValue = e.Value?.ToString();
         var formattedValue = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("formatNumberInput", _currentValue, AllowDecimals);
         _stringValue = formattedValue;

         var rawValue = formattedValue.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".");
         if (decimal.TryParse(rawValue, out var result))
         {
             Value = result;
             await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
         }
     }

     private async Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
     {
         await OnInput(e);
     }
 }




Your problem probaly lies here: await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("validateInput", _id, AllowDecimals, e); Noted that validadeInput is not a void function. Also, probably e is null or undefined here or it is not a valid JavaScript event object, which causes your exception inside the validateInput function.

I don't know why your  works, I copy your code   report a System.InvalidOperationException mistake. You can learn more about  "InputNumber" from this website : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/input-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0
